# TypeError: products.groupBy is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I was reading that JS recently introduced a new array method `groupBy` to manipulate an array such

```
const products = [
  { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
];
```

the that this code

```
const groupByCategory = products.groupBy(product => {
  return product.category;
});
console.log(groupByCategory)
```

should produce this output

```
// {
//   'fruits': [
//     { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' }, 
//     { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
//   ],
//   'vegetables': [
//     { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
//   ]
// }
```

however, I have used `node 18.7.0` but the log saying `TypeError: products.groupBy is not a function`
My question does this method works on any of node version?

**Note** that I don't to use `reduce`

Comment: you can use `filter()` Also check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group
but this is in an experimental stage.

Comment: are you using a polyfill. anyway even with a polyfill it is now `group`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: products.group is not a function

Comment: So it's not supported by Node.js (yet).

Comment: it is still in stage 3 and not supported by node yet. you can either use a polyfill. or lodash or just custom grouping using `reduce`

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript Reduce() method to make Group By Like SQL

```
            const products = [
              { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
              { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
              { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
            ];

            var result = products.reduce((x, y) => {

                (x[y.category] = x[y.category] || []).push(y);

                return x;

            }, {});

            console.log(result);

            Output:  {fruits: Array(2), vegetables: Array(1)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using functionality is in a testing state you must install its dependency using `npm i core-js`, then you can access this functionality by importing. ex

```
require("core-js/actual/array/group-by-to-map");
require("core-js/actual/array/group-by");

const products = [
  { name: "apples", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "oranges", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "potatoes", category: "vegetables" }
];

const groupByCategory = products.groupBy((product) => {
  return product.category;
});

const groupByCategoryMap = products.groupByToMap((product) => {
  return product.category;
});

console.log(groupByCategory);
console.log(groupByCategoryMap);
```

You can see this in the same example where they talk about its use
[Read Here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-group/), if you look at the code examples given in that forum it requires importing and installing core-js [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js).

Comment: import 'core-js/actual'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: thanks that was very helpful, however, this should be require or at least in my case
require("core-js/actual/array/group-by");

Comment: I tried switching from imports to require and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

`groupBy` is not a function in Node.js. You should first import it and then use it.

- First, install: `npm i core-js`
- Then, import:

  ```js
  import { groupBy } from "core-js/actual/array/group-by";

  const groupByCategoryMap = products.groupBy(product => product.category);
  ```